# Images loaded through JavaScript are throwing me CORS errors even though it's enabled

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-domain, cors

I'm using PaintbrushJS to colorize cross-domain images that're loaded via JS, but every time I try, I get a warning in Chrome: `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.`  I have the appropriate CORS header and `crossOrigin="anonymous"` thrown onto the images.

Here's the thing, if I have the `<img>`'s `src` hardcoded into the HTML, I still get the error, but the colorizing actually works, which leads me to believe that once an image is loaded via JS, it becomes re-tainted.  What's weird is that I can throw these "re-tainted" images onto a canvas and read from that without any cross-origin warnings.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you have the `crossOrigin="anonymous"` attribute on the image, the browser won't like it if the image doesn't return a proper CORS header.